# Updating column name with source system where data comes from

Tags: ssis

Am new to `SSIS` and started learning sample projects.

Am trying to do the below task and am not sure how to start and i didn't get much in Google as well.

Example Scenario:

I have created `"Student"` table in my DB. `Student Columns : Id,Name,Class,Section,Source`

and am trying to pull the data for this table from different Data Sources like `A,B,C`

Am trying to insert data to my School table from A,B,C sources

1 row : how am updating `**A** will insert in Id **A** will insert in Name **B** will insert in Class **C** will insert Section`

and in `Source Column` of table i need to have some format mentioning which data-source each column comes from like `Id:A,Name:A,Class:B,Section:C`

Sample o/p

```
Id|Name  | Class|  Section |  Source
1 | Test | Test | test     | Id:A,Name:A,Class:B,Class:C
2 | Test2| Test | test     | Id:A,Name:A,Class:B,Class:C
```

What i did ?

I tried pulling the data from sources but i didn't find a way to update my Source section.

how do i implement this scenario.. ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the package design as to how you are pulling the data from different sources and inserting into destination

Comment: @praveen i tried with DataFlow and am not sure how to update the source

Comment: Whatever you do, please do not put all your source data into one column. Instead, add 4 columns for `SourceID, SourceName, SourceClass1, SourceClass2` or whatever. Putting multiple values into one column only creates problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would add columns to each Data Flow Source with values e.g

```
Data source A = 'Id:A,Name:A'
Data source B = 'Class:B'
Data source C = 'Class:C'
```

Then I would concatenated them together in a Derived Column transformation, and deliver them through the existing Data Flow Destination.